# Сontainer Bootstrap padding

Tags: bootstrap, padding

Здравствуйте!
Возник вопрос на Bootstrap c классом container Заданы Padding 15px при высчитавании он не прибавляет в ширине в высчитывает внутрь элемента как это сделано я не понял у меня так не получается. [image: Внутренние Padding] как же он высчитывается у меня с таким же классом padding прибавляет в ширине а тут высчитывает внутрь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`box-sizing: border-box` примени к классу container

Comment: Спасибо! помогло